# Cannot register Sybase 15 ASE OLE DB driver on Windows 7

Tags: oledb, sap-ase

I am trying to get the Sybase 15 ASE OLE DB driver set up on my Windows 7 machine. I already have the Adaptive Server Enterprise driver listed in the Drivers tab of my 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe).

I tried to re-register the DLL with the command `regsvr32 sybdrvoledb.dll` and with `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe sybdrvoledb.dll` from a command prompt running as admin, and in both cases I get back "DllRegisterServer in sybdrvoledb.dll succeeded" but when I check in the ODBC administrator the driver is still not listed. Is there another way to get the ODBC administrator to recognize the OLE DB driver?

My goal is to be able to create the System DSN named ASEOLEDB that uses the OLE DB driver. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Sybase 15 to see if ASEOLEDB would be created automatically and it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Try launching C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe which will show you the 32 bit drivers. The other ODBC administrator which you're probably launching is located in C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe

Comment: I am using the 32-bit version at that path. After talking to others, my understanding now is that ASEOLEDB does not show up in the ODBC Data Source Admin because it is not an ODBC conenction - it is an OLE DB connection. The issue I thought this would resolve had a different root cause.